# How do I double the speed of the Start Screen effects in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen, visual-effects

When I say double the speed, I mean make the effects happen twice as fast.

I only want the Start Screen effects to be modified, however if I had to modify all effect speeds that'd work too.

The effects I'm referring to are:

- When you press the [image: 1] key on your keyboard, it kind of "flows" in. [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUeW1sXk55k)
- When you search the search results move around instead of just showing up. [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rf_oMubwMgI)

Comment: Double your hardware speed

Comment: I can't tell, are you jokingly telling me to buy more RAM or something or is this really a solution?

Comment: Yea, upgrade your gfx card. Everything will render much more rapidly.

Comment: It's an artificial limit. The only reason it was lagging in the video was because of camtasia, which seems to lag my computer (even though it's a high-end one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [Start Screen Animations Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.146) and [this official PowerShell script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-tweak-Start-86eb3087) let you change all the animation-related settings possible, including the parallax effect speed (but not the speed of the animations you want):

[image: 1]

Comment: So, this will change all speeds or all speeds but the ones I want?

Comment: See the video on the site. I don't think there's any way to change the speeds of the animations you want via the registry (they might be hard-coded), or at least no way that's been found yet. AFAIK these settings are all that are currently possible to modify.

Comment: Hmph. Hopefully with windows blue it's possible.